# Scratch Org - Generate Keys automatically

Tags: scratch-org, platform-encryption, shield-encryption, scratch-org-definition-file

I would like to know if anyone has a way of generating platform encryption keys when building a scratch org?

Currently, the way I know is to Create a Permission set with:

- MANAGE ENCRYPTION KEYS
- MANAGE CERTIFICATES

Then assign this permission set to the System Admin user in order for me to have the option to generate keys under the *Security > Platform Encryption > Key Management* section

Answer (score 3):

We created automation (scripting) that handles this and other aspects when we create scratch orgs. Here's the relevant section of our script (this is our CI version that runs in bitbucket pipelines but it should give the idea - what I show is necessarily incomplete in order to not expose us in any way but should help you understand what you can do):

```
# Decrypt server key
- openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -d -in bitbucket-pipelines-assets/server.key.enc -out bitbucket-pipelines-assets/server.key -base64 -K $DECRYPTION_KEY -iv $DECRYPTION_IV
# Authorize Dev Hub
- sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid $HUB_CONSUMER_KEY --jwtkeyfile bitbucket-pipelines-assets/server.key --username $HUB_USER_NAME --setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias HubOrg
# Create scratch org
- sfdx force:org:create --targetdevhubusername HubOrg --setdefaultusername --definitionfile config/scratch-def.json --setalias ciorg --wait 10 --durationdays 1
# Push manage encryption permissions
- sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-build/main/default/permissionsets/Manage_Encryption.permissionset-meta.xml --targetusername ciorg
# Set manage encryption permissions
- sfdx force:apex:execute -f bitbucket-pipelines-assets/encryption-permissions.apex --targetusername ciorg
# Create tenant secret in the scratch org
- sfdx force:data:record:create -s TenantSecret -v "Description=XYZ" --targetusername ciorg
```

Note how we have a special folder structure, `force-build`, that isn't part of the standard `force-app` source tree. We hold resources here needed as part of the "build" (i.e. scratch org creation). The important one for Shield is the Manage_Encryption perm set:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PermissionSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <label>Manage Encryption</label>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>CustomizeApplication</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageCustomPermissions</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ManageEncryptionKeys</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewRoles</name>
    </userPermissions>
    <userPermissions>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <name>ViewSetup</name>
    </userPermissions>
</PermissionSet>
```

On top of that we have a number of Apex scripts that we run during the build. The important one for Shield handling is "encryption-permissions.apex":

```
// Give the user the required permission set
List<PermissionSet> sets = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = 'Manage_Encryption'];
List<User> users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Alias = 'UUser'];

if (!sets.isEmpty() && !users.isEmpty()) {
    PermissionSetAssignment assignment = new PermissionSetAssignment(
            PermissionSetId = sets[0].Id,
            AssigneeId = users[0].Id);

    insert assignment;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I automated this aswell for creating a scratchorg and ran into some issues when i wanted to push PlatformEncryptionSettings alongside it.

However I found the following solution in terms of CLI-execution order:

1. Create Org
2. Deploy the permissionset
3. Assign the permissionset to Admin
4. Deploy the permissionset settings (for instance:
   sf deploy metadata --metadata-dir {relative path to permissionset which holds map named settings, with the settings, and a package.xml}
   -l NoTestRun -g -w 180
5. Generate **another** tenantsecret, regarding the settings you deployed. For example: sf data create record -s TenantSecret -v "Description=ABC Type=DeterministicData"